# Leaving major cities during COVID-19 pandemic

Tags: usa, covid-19, pandemics

My wife and I live in a major US city (Chicago) and are considering leaving for now to stay with family in a rural area a few hours away. Our reasons for this are mostly safety, seeing some of the reactions to toilet paper/groceries being low makes us both very concerned for what kind of civil unrest might happen in the coming weeks.

Our thoughts for why it would be good to go:

- Avoid possible looting/rioting/violence
- Emotional reasons (being with family, having more space)
- Easier to keep distance from people with a much smaller population around you

Possible reasons to stay where we are:

- Possibly spreading the virus (my wife has had a light cough for a few days, but no other symptoms)
- Health organizations asking us to stay put (although we would remain inside once we got to the new place)
- Maybe we're just overreacting and the chance of civil unrest right now is very low

I would like to know if there are any official recommendations on if this kind of travel is discouraged/forbidden, or even unofficial reasons why one option might be better than the other. Please let me know if this belongs in another network or if I should add/remove anything.

UPDATE:

Thanks for the advice, you've all made us reconsider and we'll be staying put to not risk spreading anything.

Comment: With a new, albeit light, cough as a symptom, in the UK at least the instruction is for the entire household to self-isolate at home for 14 days. So no travel to your relatives until you’re sure you’re not taking an unwelcome guest along with you.

Comment: A further consideration is that you are unlikely to be the only person to come up with this plan. There have been news reports in the UK today of three separate "isolated" areas seeing a large influx of "vistors," and creating new potential hotspots for transmission.

Comment: Your age, and the age of the rest of the family might be relevant here. The number of family members that will be together is important too. Also, what access would you have to health care if you stay where you are? All these are risk factors.

Comment: @alephzero Plus extra pressure on local health services and food supplies https://apple.news/ABEGafcV5Tv6czs2rUPXPzA

Comment: "Avoid possible looting/rioting/violence" - sorry but is this a real concern in the US? Here (Israel) covid is bad, and it's also really bad all around the world - as far as I know no looting is occuring and people are showing solidarity and strength. Is the US vibe different?

Comment: @Benjamin there aren't any reports of violence right now, the fact that things are changing so fast has me worries though. A week ago people were still deciding if they should go into the gym or not (for example), and within a few days there's a shelter in place order. So probably an overreaction to expect violence right now, but it's still a balancing act between being alarmist and being prepared.

Comment: @wearebob thank you for taking the situation seriously and taking the time to gather information and educate yourself before taking that kind of decision! I'm glad to hear that you'll be staying in town to help limit the spread of the virus!

Comment: A factor in your determination would be the availability of health services where you are going. I would think that going from the city to rural would make outcomes more extreme (i.e. if you end up needing care, it'll be much worse - but if you end up NOT needing care, it'll be easier). Any city health care system is likely to be less overwhelmed than a rural one - given the same rate of infection. (rural health care is *usually* underdimensioned and city health care centers will be first in line for federal / military aid)

Comment: In regards to looting/violence, I recommend looking at how your area handled the [1918 flu pandemic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanish_flu).  If there wasn't looting and violence then, there probably won't be now.

Comment: Many spaniards did this hours before the lockdown and it helped to greatly spread the virus, so I'd suggest anyone to just stay at their home and wait until this is gone

Comment: @Mark that's a really terrible argument.  That would be like saying in 2013 that ferguson missouri would never have any unrest over civil rights abuses because it didn't happen in the 60s.  Things change.  What happened a century ago has no predictive power for what might happen today.

Comment: @eps your argument strengthens Mark's position, because in fact there was a good deal of civil unrest over civil rights abuses in the 1960's.

Comment: @Studoku-ReinstateMonica probably because your question was essentially "how can I flee," whereas this one is "should I flee," and the answer is *no.*

Comment: Remember this feeling of helplessness, if you survive this crisis.  Remember being unsure if you could defend yourself in your own home.  And when this is over, talk to your lawmakers and elected representatives about making it easier for law abiding citizens like yourself to responsibly own firearms.  If your land today called Chicago is still called that after this crisis is over, speak at city council and at your state legislature about what Illinois' heightened restrictions on access to defensive weapons meant to you in these troubled times.  And good luck and god bless!

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Clearly yes, it's a real concern; just not over Covid-19.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Travel of this sort is either permitted or it's not. If there are restrictions on travel in your area you should follow them. If there are not then it's allowed.

For example, if you were in Italy or France on this day (March 21 2020) then such travel would be forbidden - it's not essential travel. As I understand it there are no restrictions on internal travel in the US - but that's the situation today and it could be different tomorrow.

You should also listen to the advice of medical professional about what is discouraged. Anything you do that increases contact increases the chance of spreading Covid-19 is going to make the overall situation worse - and most kinds of travel will result in increased contact. If your medical professionals are asking you not to travel unnecessarily, don't do it.

Comment: Good answer.  I would just add that anybody doing this is being rather selfish.  You might already have the virus without knowing it, due to the long incubation time before symptoms show, and that means that you will spread it to remote communities where medical facilities are not as well advanced and not able to cope as well.  As you may also then suffer due to the same reasons.

Comment: @jason.kaisersmith Thanks, you're right and it would be selfish of us. We've decided to stay where we are like pretty much everyone is advocating.

Comment: There are no _nationwide_ restrictions restrictions on internal travel in the US, but some parts of the country have already imposed such restrictions locally. In fact, according to the other answer, Illinois is already under a restriction.

Comment: It's hard to see how car travel increases contact if you keep your distance when filling up, perhaps use a self service station. In a relatively crowded city you are likely to have more contact.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica The problem is not risk of them spreading the virus during the actual travel. The risk is that they would create a new hot spot by bringing the virus to a previously isolated area. It seems to be possible for someone with no symptoms, or very minimal symptoms, to be contagious.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica Another problem is that the place you are going to has an amount of health care scaled to the normal number of residents. If people move to other places they couild overwhelm the he4ath system. See quotes from Doctors in Wales, Cornwall, Scotland etc.

Answer (score 50):

The question asks "I would like to know if there are any official recommendations on if this kind of travel is discouraged/forbidden, or even unofficial reasons why one option might be better than the other."

In the US, travel and similar restrictions are being handled mainly by state and local governments. Chicago is in Illinois.

The State of Illinois has prohibited non-essential travel. See [EXECUTIVE ORDER IN RESPONSE TO COVID-19 (COVID-19 EXECUTIVE ORDER NO. 8)](https://www2.illinois.gov/Documents/ExecOrders/2020/ExecutiveOrder-2020-10.pdf).

"All travel, including, but not limited to, travel by automobile, motorcycle, scooter, bicycle, train, plane, or public transit, except Essential Travel and Essential Activities as defined herein, is prohibited."

The various essential activities listed in the order do not seem to me to cover leaving Chicago to stay with relatives or to avoid potential civil unrest.

Comment: You're allowed to leave to go take care of family members.

Comment: @JonathanReez It would indeed be different if the question had been about going to take care of the relatives.

Comment: @JonathanReez: indeed, that would work only if the OP lied. Anyway, he has decided to stay, so the point is moot.

Comment: @QuoraFeans Could be less a lie than a true and exploitable side effect.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica In practice, stay at home and travel ban orders would be somewhere between extremely difficult and impossible to enforce. Lives depend on responsible people like the OP deciding to follow them anyway.

Answer (score 15):

In Norway people have done exactly this, and now the military is forcing people to return to their homes. They argued, that healthcare in rural areas is minimal or nonexistent, and that if the people get sick later, they will either overrun the rural healthcare centers, or not get treatment at all.

[Coronavirus: Norwegians told to leave countryside cabins and return home](https://www.thelocal.no/20200315/norwegians-told-to-leave-countryside-cabins-and-return-home)

[“Go Home!” Norway PM Orders Norwegians to Leave Mountain Cabins](https://www.lifeinnorway.net/norway-cabin-fever/)

Comment: Same in several more European countries.

Comment: Both articles say the government "will deploy the civil defence to bring people home from their cabins if necessary", but neither of them says "now the military is forcing people to return to their homes" as you claim. I suggest either editing your answer or providing additional sources to back your claim.

Comment: I couldn't find English articles that used those exact words, because I first read about it in a Finnish newspaper, and then Googled for English articles to be linked here.

Comment: In the USA some states are requiring anyone from New York (and sometimes Louisiana) to self-isolate for 14 days. I agree with the Norwegian military, because I know from experience that entire large counties in the USA may have very little medical infrastructure (e. g. no MRI, no intensive care), so if someone did get a serious case of COVID-19 they'd have to be driven right back to the metropolitan area they just fled.

Answer (score 8):

### If you do, self-isolate for 14 days *before* getting close to family.

Don't be "that guy" - you know the one.  The selfish one who becomes the "index patient" for that county.

Treat it just the same as New Zealand is treating visitors.  Can you go on a 6-week grand tour of the Lord of the Rings filming sites and all of NZ's wonders?  Welcome with open arms -- but you'll be spending the first 14 days sequestered in a hotel room.

They have the right idea. Do that.

If your rural friends have a lick of sense, they'll make you do that anyway.  Unfortunately many people do not have a lick of sense, and in the moment of hello, are *far* more concerned with being viewed as disapproving or stand-off-ish, and cannot resist going in for that hug.

So I wouldn't even see the family until day 15 and would stay in a hotel.  Unless they *really get it*, and have a fully isolated in-law apartment they can toss you into.

### Don't trust the country, either

Also don't go assuming everyone in the country is immune. You're not the only one doing this.  You could sit out the 14 days and feel safe being all hugs... and unbeknownst to you 2 days earlier your family spent time with the Joneses who made contact 2 days prior with "that guy".

Operating on emotion will not work (wishful thinking, fear, etc).  Operating on science, fact and unflinching care is the only reliable thing.  **And that's hard enough when you have to cat-herd a whole family** into good practices they don't really believe in.

One more thing. Guns. There are lots of guns out there.  Either don't touch them, or **go all-in**, learning gun safety, especially gun law (rules of engagement), then gun self-defense (guns are not an "I win button") - and squeeze off *bare minimum* 300 rounds among at least 5 trips to the range.

Comment: Self isolating in a mountain cabin with 3 months foods, a gun for hunting, and having zero contact with other people is probably the safest place to be at the moment.

Comment: Nitpicking: learning safe gun *practice* while in isolation is IMHO going to be very hard as the isolation means that there cannot be anyone standing with you at the range (or backyard if that's a possibility there) and yell at you as soon as you start doing something that is not safe. Self-defense even more so.

Comment: @cbeleites yeah, it would have to be after isolation. Hopefully the desperation/roving gangs/Mad Max can wait 14 days+range time.

Comment: The guy is in Chicago.  He is not going to be able to go out and buy a gun if he doesn't have one already.  He needs an FOID card before he can purchase there.  And those take months to get nowadays.

Comment: @BillyC. I'm more thinking guns lent by their host.

Answer (score 3):

Let's suppose you succeed in getting away to your family living a few hours distant.

Have you stopped to consider the probable reaction of others in the community there. Things have got very nasty in the Scottish Highlands in relation to numerous campervans and motorhomes coming from England to escape the Coronavirus, overwhelming the limited food resources in a time of shortage, causing a health hazard as campsites have been closed by government order, and potentially overhwhelming overstressed medical facilities in a remote and scattered area.
You can probably expect a violent reaction from many of the locals.

Comment: The New York Times is reporting similar reception in Florida and other areas where people from New York City and its suburbs have been going to stay in their weekend homes, in their vacation homes, with friends and relatives, etc.